# CSS selectors to be used for scraping specific links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am new to Python and working on a scraping project. I am using Firebug to copy the CSS path of required links. I am trying to collect the links under the tab of "UPCOMING EVENTS" from http://kiascenehai.pk/ but it is just for learning how I can get the specified links.

I am looking for the fix of this problem and also suggestions for how to retrieve specified links using CSS selectors.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://kiascenehai.pk/"

r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.select("html body div.body-outer-wrapper div.body-wrapper.boxed-mode div.main-     outer-wrapper.mt30 div.main-wrapper.container div.row.row-wrapper div.page-wrapper.twelve.columns.b0 div.row div.page-wrapper.twelve.columns div.row div.eight.columns.b0 div.content.clearfix section#main-content div.row div.six.columns div.small-post-wrapper div.small-post-content h2.small-post-title a"):
    print  link.get('href')
```

Comment: Can you help me fix and learn how to get useful css selectors ? @Martijn Pieters

Comment: The URL you are loading *asks for a city to be picked* at `http://kiascenehai.pk/select_city?url=http%3A%2F%2Fkiascenehai.pk%2F`, and contains no upcoming events for me. When I pick 'Lahore', say, a cookie is set. You need to make sure that `requests` does the same.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how it could be made possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that page requires a city selection to be made (in a cookie). Use a [Session object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to handle this:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.post('http://kiascenehai.pk/select_city/submit_city', data={'city': 'Lahore'})
response = s.get('http://kiascenehai.pk/')
```

Now the response gets the actual page content, not redirected to the city selection page.

Next, keep your CSS selector no larger than needed. In this page there isn't much to go on as it uses a grid layout, so we first need to zoom in on the right rows:

```
upcoming_events_header = soup.find('div', class_='featured-event')
upcoming_events_row = upcoming_events_header.find_next(class_='row')

for link in upcoming_events_row.select('h2 a[href]'):
    print link['href']
```

Comment: will you explain a bit why you used .find_next method here ? What is it actually for ? @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @Flecha: see [the `.find_next()` documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next); it scans through the element tree finding the requested element, but doesn't search the whole document, only *after the starting point*.

Comment: @Flecha: so it is just like a normal `find`, but it doesn't look at anything before the `upcoming_events_header` element.

Comment: @Flecha: the accept is much appreciated, btw. Did the code in the other answer also work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is co-founder KiaSceneHai.pk; please don't scrape websites, alot of effort goes into collecting the data, we offer access through our API, you can use the contact form to request access, ty