# Grab the value of a tags attribute using bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using **bs4** with **Python3** to grab the details of a product searched on **amazon** ,
 here is my code :

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS 
 import requests

 html = requests.get('http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-
 alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hp+monitors')

 soup = BS(html.text , 'lxml')
 #print(soup.prettify())

 for i in soup.find_all('li') :
    print(i.get('id'))
    h2_tag = i.h2
    print(h2_tag.get('data-attribute'))
    print("_____")
```

With this code i am not getting the value of **data-attribute** attribute of **h2** tag . Whereas the value of **id** attribute of **li** tag is coming out .
Can anyone tell where i am doing mistake .

[image: html to scrap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to say here:

1. instead of using `html.text`, use [as recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24801950/4489998) `html.content`.
2. why would you use `lxml` here ? `html.parser` should be fine.
3. there is no need to use the `data-attribute` tag: you can just grab the text from the h2 using `h2.text`.

A simpler way to gather the product titles is directly iterating through all of the `<h2>` that have the `s-inline` class (the product titles):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get('http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hp+monitors')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content , 'html.parser')

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2', class_='s-inline'):
    print(h2.text)
```

Output

```
HP 24ES 23.8-HP 24ES 23.8-inch THINNEST LED Monitor (Black)LED Monitor (Black)
HP 22es Display 54.6 cm, 21.5 Inch THINNEST IPS LED Backlit Monitor
HP 22KD 21.5-inch FULL HD LED Backlit Monitor (Black
HP 19KA 18.5-inch LED Backlit Monitor (Black)
HP 27es 27 Inches Display IPS LED Backlit Monitor (Full HD)
HP 21KD 20.7-inch FULL HD LED Backlit Monitor (Black)
LG 24MP88HV-S 24"IPS Slim LCD Monitor
Dell S Series S2415H 24-Inch Screen Full HD HDMI LED Monitor
Dell E1916HV 18.5-inch LED Monitor (Black)
HP 20KD 19.5-inch LED Backlit Monitor (Black)
Dell S2216H 21.5-Inch Full HD LED Monitor
HP V222 21.5" LED Widescreen Monitor (M1T37AA Black)
AlexVyan®-Genuine Accessory with 1 year warranty:= (38.1CM) 15 Inch LCD Monitor for HP, Dell, Lenovo, Pc Desktop Computer Only (Black)
Compaq B191 18.5-inch LED Backlit Monitor (Black)
HP 20WD 19.45-Inch LED Backlit Monitor
HP Compaq F191 G9F92AT 18.5-inch Monitor
```

---

Also, instead of using bold for inline code, use backticks like this:

`codecode` will be rendered as `codecode`

---

**EDIT:**

Here, `soup.find_all('h2')` would have gotten all h2 tags from the page, however the amazon page also has h2 tags for other elements than products. I just noticed that all products had the `s-inline` class, so `soup.find_all('h2', class_='s-inline")` will only take the h2 tags from products.

Comment: Thankyou , How is the >soup.find_all('h2', class_='s-inline'): working ?