# How can I use Python's Beautiful Soup to find the value of a custom attribute?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

For example:

```
div data3456 = "some value"
```

`data3456` is a custom attribute for the `div`.  How can I scan the html looking for "data3456" and find "some value"?

Comment: Please explain more details ! edit your question and insert the full `div` and the code which you trying with !

Comment: Welcome to SO! There should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar logic which is used here: 
[How to use CSS selectors to retrieve specific links lying in some class using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801548/how-to-use-css-selectors-to-retrieve-specific-links-lying-in-some-class-using-be)
.

Try this:

```
for el in upcoming_events_div.select('div[data3456]'):
    print el['data3456']
```