# How to use CSS selectors to retrieve specific links using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im using python for scraping the following page: [alfabeta.surge.sh](https://alfabeta.surge.sh/) and i would like to get the link in (#home1 > div:nth-child(10) > table:nth-child(29) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > a )

Actually im doing this:

```
import bs4, requests
res = requests.get('https://alfabeta.surge.sh/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('a')[23].attrs.get('href')
```

But if the position of the  change i cant download the content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use CSS selectors to retrieve specific links lying in some class using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801548/how-to-use-css-selectors-to-retrieve-specific-links-lying-in-some-class-using-be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make some assumptions about what is most likely to remain constant, and then review over time. For example, I might assume you want the 3rd column `td`'s child `a` tag `href`, from the `table` which is the first following the `div` with containing the string `Catálogo Actualizaciones`. One css pattern for that would be as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://alfabeta.surge.sh/')
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('div:-soup-contains("Catálogo Actualizaciones") ~ table td:nth-child(3) > a')['href'])
```

Comment: i tried to do that but response {NotImplementedError}':-soup-contains' pseudo-class is not implemented at this time

Comment: `print(soup.select_one('div:contains("Catálogo Actualizaciones") ~ table td:nth-child(3) > a')['href'])`

Comment: Or upgrade your bs4/soupsieve to latest.